# Trouble getting right elements from xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have the following xml:

```
 <TEI>
  <xi:include href="header.xml"/>
  <text>
   <body>
    <!-- morph_1-p is akapit 7300 with instances (akapit_transzy-s) 14598, 14618 in batches (transza-s) 1461, 1463 resp. -->
    <p corresp="ann_segmentation.xml#segm_1-p" xml:id="morph_1-p">
     <s corresp="ann_segmentation.xml#segm_1.35-s" xml:id="morph_1.35-s">
      <seg corresp="ann_segmentation.xml#segm_1.1-seg" xml:id="morph_1.1-seg">
       <fs type="morph">
        <f name="orth">
         <string>Sami</string>
        </f>
        <!-- Sami [0,4] -->
        <f name="interps">
         <fs type="lex" xml:id="morph_1.1.1-lex">
          <f name="base">
           <string>sam</string>
          </f>
          <f name="ctag">
           <symbol value="adj"/>
          </f>
          <f name="msd">
           <vAlt>
            <symbol value="pl:nom:m1:pos" xml:id="morph_1.1.1.1-msd"/>
            <symbol value="pl:voc:m1:pos" xml:id="morph_1.1.1.2-msd"/>
           </vAlt>
          </f>
         </fs>
        </f>
        <f name="disamb">
         <fs feats="#an8003" type="tool_report">
          <f fVal="#morph_1.1.1.1-msd" name="choice"/>
          <f name="interpretation">
           <string>sam:adj:pl:nom:m1:pos</string>
          </f>
         </fs>
        </f>
       </fs>
      </seg>
```

In this xml only the  nodes are repeated (all parent nodes of  occur only once)

I am trying to get:

```
        <f name="orth">
         <string>Sami</string>
        </f>
```

and:

```
          <f name="interpretation">
           <string>sam:adj:pl:nom:m1:pos</string>
          </f>
```

There is no case in the entire xml that those are missing.

This is my code:

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStreamReader);
    inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeListSeg = document.getElementsByTagName("seg");
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeListSeg.getLength(); i++) {
        if(nodeListSeg.item(i).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            words.add(((Element) nodeListSeg.item(i).getFirstChild().getFirstChild()).getTextContent().trim());
        if(nodeListSeg.item(i).getLastChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            words.add(((Element) nodeListSeg.item(i).getLastChild()).getTextContent().trim());
    }
    inputStreamReader.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

One other approach that I tried was to check through values of attributes:

```
if(((Element) nodeListSeg.item(i).getFirstChild()).getAttribute("name").equals("orth")) {...}
if(((Element) nodeListSeg.item(i).getFirstChild()).getAttribute("name").equals("interpretation"))
```

But this comparison never returns true.

Comment: after some tests: `NodeList nodeListSeg = document.getElementsByTagName("seg");` populates the NodeList with 3 child nodes of types: fs, text, text. Can someone point does elements out (which is which)?

Comment: the `text` nodes return empty strings when called. `for(int j = 0; j < nodeListChildren.getLength(); j++) {
      if(nodeListChildren.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
       System.out.println(nodeListChildren.item(j).getNodeValue().trim());
      }`

Answer (score 0):

The solution turns out to be like this:

```
NodeList nodeListSeg = document.getElementsByTagName("seg");
for(int i = 0; i < nodeListSeg.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList nodeListChildren = nodeListSeg.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for(int j = 0; j < nodeListChildren.getLength(); j++) {
        if(nodeListChildren.item(j).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String text = ((Element) nodeListChildren.item(j)).getTextContent().toLowerCase().trim();
            String[] stringArray = text.split(" ");
            System.out.println(stringArray[0] + "\t" + stringArray[stringArray.length - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

So it turns out all the `text` nodes in the `FS` node didn't get parsed correctly and are all considered as one single element.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, XPath is a much better alternative here:

```
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new File(...));

    XPath xp = XPathFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newXPath();

    String s1 = (String) xp.evaluate("//f[@name='orth']/string/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(s1);
    String s2 = (String) xp.evaluate("//f[@name='interpretation']/string/text()", doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
    System.out.println(s2);
```